# Android - Get Other Layout Widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've been trying to get a widget from another layout for past hours but still no luck. Can someone tell what is wrong with my current code?

```
public void refreshClicked(View view){

    tab1 = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_1, null);
    Button b = (Button) tab1.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    b.setText("Updating...");


}
```

I've hooked my button `onClick` to `refreshClicked(View view)` method.

This method is under my MainActivity.java and I'm trying to get the Button with `id` `refresh` from `tab_1.xml` layout but the button text is not updating.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access an already existing view or to create a new one ? because here you inflate a new view but you don't seems to use it.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm trying to access an existing view. Basically, I'm trying to get widgets from one of my tabs.

Comment: Ok, and the view parameter you are passing to refreshClicked() is the view of your tab/widget ?

Comment: I really have no idea, mate. I just set my button property `onClick` to `refreshClick` from dropdown menu. I assume they automatically supply the View parameter.

Comment: Just provide your activity/tabs xml view and we be able to debug your code

Comment: I got it, bro. I just directly access the widget from my main activity. 

          Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
          b.setText("Updating....");

;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to inflate a layout but never attach it to a parent view as the ViewGroup parameter is null. Then this layout inflated must not even been displayed anywhere.

If the button b already exists, no need to inflate the layout and retrieve the button form there, it will a different button.
Just retrieve the button from the actual existing layout.

Comment: And it worked! Why did I even have to add `tab1 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_1, null);` I thought findViewById won't work if you're not on the layout you're trying to access. I was wrong XD Thanks bro!